# Compiler thinks boolean variable is unused

Tags: rust, shadowing

I'm playing with session types for rust, and i have a pretty simple function that does that following:

```
fn srv(c: Chan<(), Server>){
    let (c, n) = c.recv();
    let tmp = false;
    if n % 2 == 0 {
        let tmp = true;
    } else {
        let tmp = false;
    }
    let c = c.send(tmp);
    
    let (c, s) = c.recv();

    println!("server side: {}", s);


    c.close();
}
```

When I try to compile this, the rust compiler thinks that the `tmp` variable is unused.
This seems strange to me, since I am passing it to the `recv` function.

```text
warning: unused variable: `tmp`
  --> src/main.rs:25:13
   |
25 |         let tmp = false;
   |             ^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_tmp`
```

I tried playing around by making it mutable, which didnt help.

If I print it, the warning goes away. But why is it even there when I am using it for the send function?

Comment: Rust, like most languages, has block-level scope - so those inner `tmp`s that the compiler is warning you about are different variables from the outer one, and are literally never used. If you're trying to reassign to the outer one, remove the `let`s in both places (you'll have to make the outer variable `mut` as well).

Comment: If you do a bit of debugging you'll find that `tmp` is *never* `true`, because you're creating a *new* variable with the same name inside a lower scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> since I am passing it to the recv function.

No, that is the other `tmp` defined outside the `if`/`else` scopes.

What you want:

```rust
let mut tmp = false;
if n % 2 == 0 {
    tmp = true;
} else {
    tmp = false;
}
```

Or:

```rust
let tmp;
if n % 2 == 0 {
    tmp = true;
} else {
    tmp = false;
}
```

Or:

```rust
let tmp = if n % 2 == 0 {
    true
} else {
    false
};
```

Or:

```rust
let tmp = n % 2 == 0;
```

Comment: Your first example still generates a warning (`value assigned to tmp is never read`). You can replace the `let mut tmp = false;` by `let tmp;` to fix that.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I wanted to show the progression, so I added it as an intermediate step.